# How to use iAds in xcode 4.1

Tags: iphone, ios4, iad, iadstsuserex

In i Phone presently i am working with iAds concept in my project my project is successes fully run with simulator 4.1 but device 4.2.1 version fail to device error this kind of error occurred what is the reason?  My error is

```
WARNING: Falling back to active SDK directory at: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.1.sdk

GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1472) (Thu Aug  5 05:54:10 UTC 2010)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=i386-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".tty    /dev/ttys000
Loading program into debugger…
Program loaded.
target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-169-47
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
run
Running…
[Switching to thread 11523]
[Switching to thread 11523]
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
continue
warning: UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library - on disk is:
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.1.sdk
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
```

Answer (score 0):

XCode 4.1 comes with iOS 4.3 your device is running 4.2.1, thus the SDK does not match.
I've you upgrade you iOS on your device to the latest one it should work.

Or when you connect your device the organizer will ask you if it may collect the symbols from your device. If so let it collect the symbols. Then it will know which version your deice is running and it should work.

Comment: my x-code is 3.2.4 running my iads project in simulator 4.1 successfully  but device 4.2.1 is not loaded what is the reason please help me .Error is fail to device.

Comment: iPhone UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library this kind of warning occurred how to slove this error .

Comment: The UUID means that the your iOS version does not match any of the installed version on your Mac. You need to upgrade your SDK version. Download an new version of XCode with iOS SDk 4.2 or higher.